# How to email a dynamic block of HTML code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, dynamic

I am wondering if there is any way to send a block of HTML code to an email address. I have a variable that is set in an external JavaScript file named "sum" and I am calling on that variable in my html code, therefore one part of the html block is being dynamically populated. I cannot figure out how to email this the normal php way so I'm just wondering if I could just send the entire block of HTML code to an email address.

Here is the entire block of HTML code I would like to send:

```
<div class="select-location-page">
      <h2>Where should we meet you?</h2>
      <p class="location-sub-header">Fill out this form and we will meet you within 1 hour!</p>


      <form action="../mail.php" method="POST" class="location-form">

            <div class="device-details">
              <h2>Device: iPhone5</h2>
              <h2>Repair Cost: $<span id="result">0</span></h2>
            </div>

            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" maxlength="20">
            <input name="number" type="text" id="number" placeholder="Number" maxlength="15">
            <input name="address" type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address" maxlength="40">
            <input name="city" type="text" id="city" placeholder="City" maxlength="20">
            <input name="zip" type="text" id="state" placeholder="Zip" maxlength="20">

            <input name="device" type="hidden" id="device" value="iPhone5" maxlength="20">


            <div class="submit-btn">
                <input type="submit"  value="Submit Request" />
            </div>

      </form>

      <script>
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("sum");
      </script>

  </div>
```

Here is the PHP file I tried to create, all of it works except the repair cost (I've tried declaring a PHP variable in the HTML code and then putting it in the mail.php file but it did not work):

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$device = $_POST['device'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n number: $number \n Address: $address \n City: $city \n Zip $zip \n Device: $device \n Repair Cost: (need this to work)";
$recipient = "joe.t.oconnor@gmail.com";
$subject = "Device Repair Request";
$mailheader = "From: $name \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header('Location: thankyou.html');
?>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Try creating another hidden input type and dynamically setting the value of that input to the repair cost, much like you're doing with the span.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that **a lot** of e-mail clients (I'd dare to say the majority, even) will not support Javascript - not to mention the risk of the e-mail getting marked as SPAM or rejected altogether. I would advise redirecting them to a website doing this, rather than including a form in the e-mail itself.


Oh, and I just noticed..- `action="../mail.php"` won't really work when sent in an e-mail - if the form itself works to begin with (which, **it can**, but likely **won't**).

Comment: Or display sum in a readonly input so only have to update one element that gets submitted

Comment: an html form in an email will never work

Comment: @heybignick i tried putting the html block inside the value tag and it would just return the actuall html code instead of the value coming from the js file

Comment: @cup_of sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  To the best of my knowledge, you would not be able to send a block of html code with a form to an email address.  You could possibly send a link to a form with a GET variable specific for that email recipient, if that gets close to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Dagon Actually it would/could. I just tried it out along with some *buff* magic and something else ;-) got the email, filled out the form, then BAM! Got the email back.

Comment: @heybignick see my above comment to Dagon ^ and possibly the OP.

Comment: given the range of email programs surer, but if you want it to work reliably, its a real bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Consult my Edit below)

You can use output buffering to capture the form and use a full http call for the action and send as HTML.

Sidenote: Be sure to change all instances `example.com` to your server address.

Example:

```
<?php 

ob_start();

echo '

      <form action="http://www.example.com/mail.php" method="POST" class="location-form">

            <div class="device-details">
              <h2>Device: iPhone5</h2>
              <h2>Repair Cost: $<span id="result">0</span></h2>
            </div>

            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" maxlength="20">
            <input name="number" type="text" id="number" placeholder="Number" maxlength="15">
            <input name="address" type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address" maxlength="40">
            <input name="city" type="text" id="city" placeholder="City" maxlength="20">
            <input name="zip" type="text" id="state" placeholder="Zip" maxlength="20">

            <input name="device" type="hidden" id="device" value="iPhone5" maxlength="20">


            <div class="submit-btn">
                <input type="submit"  value="Submit Request" />
            </div>

      </form>

';

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$to = "email@example.com";
$from = "email@example.com";

$subject = "Form submission";

$message = $output;

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= "From:" . $from;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Then in your `mail.php` file:

Sidenote: I left out some of the POST arrays. You'll need to add those yourself. This is merely an example of something that worked for me.

```
<?php 

$first_name = $_POST['name'];

// The following is non-existant in your form. You can adjust to your liking.
$message = $_POST['message']; 

$to = "email@example.com";
$from = "email@example.com";

$subject = "Form submission 2";

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= "From:" . $from;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

---

**Footnotes:**

You may not be able to use JS here, but you can try it. I didn't use  it in my test.

You'll also have to use some form of button or link to tell people to click to send. This is an experimental answer. I will end up modifying it as soon as I can.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php

---

### Edit:

Here's how this (new one, edited) works. (You will need to add your other POST arrays to `mail.php` as discussed in comments).

Sidenote: See comments in code for some added instructions. `// comment...`

- The user enters their email address (taken from a separate form).
- If it's not empty, capture the email in a POST array.
- If the email is not empty, capture the whole thing in the output buffer.
- Sends the form to the user.

New code:

```
<?php 

echo $form = '

      <form action="" method="POST" class="location-form">

            <input name="email_from" type="text" id="email_from">

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Request" />

      </form>

';

if(!empty($_POST['email_from']) ){

// This outputs a message to the user after entering their email, and submits.
echo $from2 = "An email has been sent to: " . $_POST['email_from'];

}

$var = '

<div class="select-location-page">
      <h2>Where should we meet you?</h2>
      <p class="location-sub-header">Fill out this form and we will meet you within 1 hour!</p>


      <form action="http://www.example.com/mail.php" method="POST" class="location-form">

            <div class="device-details">
              <h2>Device: iPhone5</h2>
              <h2>Repair Cost: $<span id="result">0</span></h2>
            </div>

            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" maxlength="20">
            <input name="number" type="text" id="number" placeholder="Number" maxlength="15">
            <input name="address" type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address" maxlength="40">
            <input name="city" type="text" id="city" placeholder="City" maxlength="20">
            <input name="zip" type="text" id="state" placeholder="Zip" maxlength="20">

            <input name="device" type="hidden" id="device" value="iPhone5" maxlength="20">

            <div class="submit-btn">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Request from Email" />
            </div>

      </form>

      <script>
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("sum");
      </script>

  </div>

';

if(!empty($_POST['email_from']) ){

  ob_start();

    echo $var;

    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $to = $_POST['email_from']; // Send to the email entered by the user
    $from = "email@example.com"; // This should be YOUR E-mail address

    $subject = "Form submission";

    $message = $output;

    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $headers .= "From:" . $from;

  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);


}
```

Again, the javascript may not work for this, so you might have to think of another way or just omit it.

Comment: @FirstOne hehe no problemo ;-) I'm done anyway and do keep your comments *lol*

Comment: Just a note, I'd leave at least a link to 'output buffering' for further reading...

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for your reply! am i supposed to replace the form with the first php snippet? when i do that the form dissapears.

Comment: @FirstOne I was going to. Give me a minute.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i tried this and it seems to be displaying the form in the email that is sent but unfortunately the fields are not populated and the javascript call isnt working. is there a way to populate the fields that the user inputs as well as the variable that the javascript is calling?

Comment: @cup_of Javascript as I said in my footnotes, may not work.

Comment: @cup_of Plus, you'll need to add the extra POST arrays that are to match your named form elements. That's why it didn't send them. I have to admit, my answer is an experimental one. You'll need to modify it some.

Comment: why not just put the html in a var?

Comment: @Dagon I thought about that, but couldn't quite figure it out (yet) as well as the user entering their email address in order to receive the form. My answer is basically to demonstrate that it can be done. You're welcome to edit my answer (if you want). I have to go to bed now, but I'll be back tomorrow to work on it some more. I'll see if you did do an edit though. *Cheers*

Comment: I got a downvote but I don't mind. It's a "diamond in the rough". No idea why I got it, but it's a free world.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i dont know why u got a downvote. it wasnt me brother

Comment: @Fred-ii- i cannot upvote u to get u back to 0 because i dont have a high enough reputation :(

Comment: i would like to say though, i tried this and it does what it is supposed to do, except the javascript not working. this sends the block of html to the email address. (minus the styling)

Comment: @cup_of I've made an edit to improve my answer. Reload it and look under **Edit:** below my original answer.