# how put put dynamically populated number into input value field

Tags: html, forms, email, input

I have dynamically populated value coming from an external js file. The value is working just fine when I call it in the HTML page but I'm stuck on how to have an input field display this value.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <form action="../mail.php" method="POST" class="location-form">

        <div class="device-details">
          <h2>Device: iPhone5</h2>
          <h2>Repair Cost: <span id="result">0</span></h2>
        </div>

        <input name="device" type="hidden" id="device" value="iPhone5" maxlength="20">
        <input name="cost" type="hidden" id="cost" value="" maxlength="20">

        <div class="submit-btn">
            <input type="submit"  value="Submit Request" />
        </div>

  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("sum");
  </script>
```

at the top, in the div "device-details", the h2 "repair cost" is populating the value just fine, no issues. But I cannot seem to populate the last input with this value.

```
<input name="cost" type="hidden" id="cost" value="(need the value here)" maxlength="20">
```

I need the value of the input field to mimic the value of the repair cost at the top in order to send that value to an email address.

I've tried inserting the following into the value and it didn't work

```
value="<span id='result'>0</span>"
```

I've tried creating a variable in php and then putting the variable into the value field, and it did not work

```
<?php 
     $my_var = '<span id="result">0</span>';  
?>

value="<?php echo '$my_var'); ?>"
```

I've also tried:

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($my_var); ?>"
```

these last two just returned the actual HTML code

```
<span id="result"></span>
```

instead of the populated value.

Comment: this is a different approach from my previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193757/how-to-email-dynamic-block-of-html-code?noredirect=1#comment63813800_38193757

Comment: Do you need the html (span tags) in the input value or just the value of `sum`?

Comment: What is the input supposed to display, 0?

Comment: @mfink well i am using the span tags only to be able to give something an id of "result" this id populates the value that comes from sum. do you know another way?

Comment: @RatHat the input is supposed to display a number given by some math function in a javascript file that is linked to the page.

Comment: You can `getElementById` of the input itself (like @dulaj sanjaya's solution below) and assign it's value (no need for the spans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="abc()">
<form action="../mail.php" method="POST" class="location-form">

            <div class="device-details">
              <h2>Device: iPhone5</h2>
              <h2>Repair Cost: <span id="result">0</span></h2>
            </div>

            <input name="device" type="hidden" id="device" value="iPhone5" maxlength="20">
            <input name="cost" type="hidden" id="cost" value="" maxlength="20">

            <div class="submit-btn">
                <input type="submit"  value="Submit Request" />
            </div>

      </form>

      <script>

        function abc(){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("sum");
        document.getElementById("cost").value = localStorage.getItem("sum");
        }
      </script>

    </body>
</html>
```